# ¿Como limitar caracteres de datatable?

Tags: javascript, php, html, datatables

¿Existe alguna posibilidad de limitar la cantidad de caracteres de un datatable?

Por ejemplo la fila `empresa_reparacion`: Si el largo de caracteres es de 20 letras, como lo puedo hacer para que me muestre 10 letras.

```
<script>

      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#miTabla').DataTable( {
            "ajax":{
                "url": "Visualizacion_Reparacion/Visualizar_Reparacion_Tracto.php",
                "dataSrc":""

            },
            "columns":[
                {"data": "id_reparacion_tracto"},
                {"data": "patente_tracto"},
                {"data": "empresa_reparacion"},
                {"data": "fecha_reparacion"},
                {"data": "numero_factura_reparacion", "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
            $(nTd).html("<a href='?id="+oData.id_reparacion_tracto+"'>"+oData.numero_factura_reparacion+"</a>");
        }
    },
                {"data": "total_reparacion"},
                {"defaultContent": "<button type='button' id= name='codigo' class='btn btn-outline-primary MostrarFactura'  data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#MostrarFactura'>VISUALIZAR FACTURA</button>"},
                {"defaultContent": "<button type='button' id=${elemento.id_tracto} class='btn btn-outline-success'>MODIFICAR</button>"},   
                  {"defaultContent": "<button type='button' id=${elemento.id_tracto} class='btn btn-outline-danger'>ELIMINAR</button>"},   

            ],  
           "columnDefs": [ {
           "targets": 0,
           

     } ]
          });
      });
      
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Datatable](https://datatables.net/) ofrece para cada columna la opción de indicar, por ejemplo, una función [`render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render)

Para lo lograr lo que necesitas, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```js
...
{
  "data": "empresa_reparacion",
  "render": function (value) {
    // Si tiene mas de 20 char, devolver los 10 primeros + '...'
    if (value.length > 20) return value.substr(0, 10) + '...';
    return value;
  }
},
...
```

Comment: y si quiero por ejemplo que la fila empresa_reparacion sea solamente esa y no afecte a las demas

Comment: ¿Te referis a que se aplique cuando `id_reparacion_tracto` se igual a `x`?

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta me funciono muy bien